# refresh website meta data on facebook

Tags: facebook, metadata

I looked on the post for the problem but the developer program Lint does not seem to available.

So the problem I need to solve is Facebook keeps on pulling my very old metadata descriptions for my website whenever I link it to someone on Facebook.

How can I refresh this so the new Metadata comes up?